# Como separar numeros pares e impares separados con '@' de un String introducido por teclado?

Tags: java

Se debe introducir numeros separados por un "@" por ejemplo "12@13@14@15@" despues hay que guardar esos numeros dependendiendo si son pares o impares en un arreglo de numeros pares, o numeros impares respectivamente y por ultimo imprimir ambos arreglos.

Este es mi codigo hasta el momento.

```
    String numero = JOptionPane.showInputDialog("Digite un numero");
    char pos;
    char numeros[] = numero.toCharArray();
    String num = "";
    String impar = "";
    String par = "";


    for (int i = 0; i < numeros.length; i++) {
        if (Character.isDigit(numeros[i])) {
            num += numeros[i];

            if(Integer.parseInt(num)%2==0){
                par += num;

            }
            if(Integer.parseInt(num)%2!=0){
                impar = num;
            }
        }
    }
    JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "El numero impar es: " + impar + "\n El numero par es: " + par);

}
```

Empece probando guardar el primero numero par/impar introducido en la variable "par/impar" pero solo me funciona con los numeros que sean "par" al parecer los impares se suman de alguna manera, soy novato programando asi que trate todo lo
se me ocurrio para terminar el ejercicio pero no pude siquiera guardarlos en los arreglos. No se si de la manera que estoy tratando de hacer el ejercicio funcionara o si todo el codigo esta erroneo, no tengo que hacerlo de alguna manera especifica, asi que cualquier codigo que cumpla con lo pedido en el ejercicio es bienvenido
Gracias de antemano.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Lo primero que debe de realizar es un `split`sobre el texto ingresado

```
String numerosIngresados = JOptionPane.showInputDialog("Digite un numero"); // "12@13@14@15@"
String[] arregloNumerosIngresados = numerosIngresados.split("@"); //{"12", "13", "14", "15"}
```

Como no sabemos el tamaño de números ingresados pares o impares entonces creamos dos listas de números

```
List<Integer> numerosPares = new ArrayList<>();
List<Integer> numerosImpares = new ArrayList<>();
```

Recorres el arreglo de numeros ingresados

```
for(String numero : arregloNumerosIngresados){
  if(Integer.parseInt(numero)%2==0){
    numerosPares.add(numero);
  else{
    numerosImpares.add(numero);
  }
}
```

Ahora imprime los dos arreglos

```
System.out.println("Números pares:\n");
for(Integer par : numerosPares){
  System.out.print(par + " ");
}

System.out.println("\nNúmeros impares:\n");
for(Integer impar : numerosImpares){
  System.out.print(impar + " ");
}
```